# How to inject repository dagger dependency instance in my integration tests?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, ktor

I'm trying to access my repository dependency from my integration tests but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        RepositoryModule::class,
    ]
)
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder : AppComponent.Builder {

        override fun build(): TestAppComponent
    }
}
```

The repository module

```
@Module
interface RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    fun repository(repo: Repository): IRepository
}
```

And in my integration test :

```
class AppIntegTests {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: IRepository

    @BeforeTest
    fun setup() {
        repository.deleteAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun testRoot() {
        withTestApplication(config) {
            handleRequest { method = HttpMethod.Get; uri = "/users" }.apply {
               assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            }
            // tests....
        }
    }
}
```

When doing this, I get `lateinit property has not been initialized` on my injected repository.
Is what I'm trying to do achievable with Dagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to pass reference of `AppIntegTests` class to dagger graph in order to initialize `lateinit` property by dagger**

Add `inject` function to `TestAppComponent`

```
interface TestAppComponent  {

    fun inject(test: AppIntegTests)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): TestAppComponent
    }
}
```

call this method from `setUp` function of `AppIntegTests`

```
class AppIntegTests {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: IRepository

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val testAppComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().build()
        testAppComponent.inject(this)

        repository.deleteAll()
    }
```

Comment: I had to switch things up a bit. But your solution did put me on the right track. Thank you!